# Use of "to do" when referring to feelings

Tags: word-in-context

Is it possible to use the verb "to do" when you are referring to feelings that, at least hypothetically, you could control, like in the phrases below:

> I admit I have been a bit jealous, but you **would do** the same if you
>   were married to a woman and everywhere you go, there are always a lot
>   of men trying to get her attention.

and

> I won't deny that I'm feeling a bit nostalgic lately, but you **will probably**
>   **do** the same when you get to my age.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, "do" is a very generic verb.  It is used correctly in the original poster's examples.

"Feel" is a more specific verb that could be used instead of "do" in the original poster's examples.

"Do" is to verbs as pronouns are to nouns.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jasper. I think now everything is clear to me.

Answer (score 3):

In the way I see it, is not about feelings, is about conditional or hypothetical situations, comparing to someone else.

"If I were you, I would do the same for her"

"If you win the lottery, I will do the same as you, buying it everyday"

Comment: Hi, Honey. Thank you for your help. I was in doubt about those phrases, and maybe I still am a bit, because I was specifically talking about feelings. I think I understand you explanation about conditional or hypothetical situations and I can understand the examples you gave. I think in the phrases I used maybe the "correct" would be to say "but you would feel the same" and "but you would probably feel the same" but I was just wondering if I could use "do" instead of "feel" and yet the phrases wouldn't sound "wrong". I don't know if I'm being able to express myself correctly. Thanks again.

Comment: Right. It's nonsensical to *do* feelings. You *have* them or *experience* them. They are ***not*** an action that you perform. (Barring theatrical experiences, which isn't relevant to this question.) You simply cannot *do* feelings; that's nonsensical.